# Get username from Twitch API using Authorization Code Flow (php)

Tags: php, api, curl, oauth, twitch

I am making a program using the Twitch API that involves getting a user's username and OAuth token. Currently my website has a "Connect with Twitch" button, which will allow the user to sign into twitch and return an access token (as a GET request to my URL) I can use to contact the API and get an OAuth token. This is the code I have for that part:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "GET") {
    if (isset($_GET['code']) && !empty($_GET['code'])) {
        $code = $_GET['code'];

        //Getting OAuth
        $params = array(
            'client_id' => 'my_client_id',
            'client_secret' => 'my_client_secret',
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'redirect_uri' => 'http://mytwitchapp.com/register.php', //Not my actual url
            'code' => $code
        );

        $oauthResult = post_url_contents("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/token", $params);
        $json_decoded_oauthResult = json_decode($oauthResult, true);
        $oauth = $json_decoded_oauthResult['access_token'];


    }
}
```

This is the post_url_contents() function I use:

```
function post_url_contents($url, $fields) {
    $fields_string = '';
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.urlencode($value).'&'; }
    rtrim($fields_string, '&');

    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 60;

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);

    //SSL certificates
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, getcwd() . "/cert/DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt");

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
```

The above code works fine to get the OAuth key. I have tried submitting the `$params` array to `https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/`, which I have read should provide top-level statistics about the user, but the response I get is `You are being redirected` ("redirected" is a hyperlink to http://twitch.tv/kraken).

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after a lot of messing around, I have figured out how to do it (rather simple, it turns out).

Below the code in my first snippet, I have the following:

```
//Getting username
$usernameResult = file_get_contents("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken?oauth_token=" . $oauth);
$json_decoded_usernameResult = json_decode($usernameResult, true);
echo $username = $json_decoded_usernameResult['token']['user_name'];
```

Since I only need to send this information as a GET method instead of POST, I can just use `file_get_contents()` and append on the OAuth key to the end of the URL. After that, its just going through the returned data to get the username.